# Como evitar cortes al imprimir con react-to-print?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

tengo un pequeño inconveniente con esta libreria, y es como puedo arreglar la informacion para que no aparesca de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Justo ese corte es el que quiero evitar al momento de imprimir.

Como menciono en la pregunta estoy usando react-to-print al igual que boostrap 4, no se si hay una forma de detectar ese momento cuando hace un cambio de pagina para evitar esto.

en mi codigo seria mas o menos asi:

[HTML]:

```
<div className="list-group list-group-flush">
     {props.data.map((item, index) => (
          ... /* Se hacen ciertas comprobaciones para saber donde se ubica dato*/
     )
</div>
```

[css]:

Como mencione antes, estoy usando boostrap 4

se que hay cosas que se pueden modificar con css usando:

```
@media print{
    ...
}
```

si no mal recuerdo, entonces no se si se puede modificar desde aqui? o se puede hacer desde react, css o react?

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve el mismo problema.

Dentro del .map en data use "index + 1" para saber el "número de línea", después dependiendo de el numero le doy la orden de hacer el paso de pagina.(deberás hacer el .map antes de la sección que quieras imprimir)

En la formula miro si es múltiplo de 6 y en caso correcto haga el paso de pagina.

```
const numero = index + 1;

if(( numero % 6 ) == 0){

    const breakpage = "page-break";
    
}else{

    const breakpage = "";    
}
```

Después dentro del className pones la constante, quedaría algo así:

```
<div className={`${breakpage}`} >  </div>
```

Y ya como ultimo debes usar el CSS para personalizar los márgenes a tu gusto cuando haga el paso de pagina y que reconozca el paso de pagina.

```
    @media print {
  div.page-break {
    margin-top: 6rem;
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

No se si hay una solución mejor pero a mi me ha funcionado.
Espero que te sirva.